# ColdFusion Function Similar to PHP mb_convert_encoding

Tags: php, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Is there any ColdFusion function similar to **[mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)** in PHP?

I need to convert following PHP code to ColdFusion:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<?php
    $str = $_GET["brand"]; //%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str,'UTF-8',"SJIS");
    echo $str; //日産自動車
?>
```

In short, is there any inbuilt function in cold-fusion that converts the character encoding of string str to 'UTF-8' from 'SJIS'?

Comment: WTF? someone's voted to close "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center." What a jerk.

Comment: @AdamCameron: Even I did n't understand, why my ques conceeded one close-vote. I didn't find the answer for this question any where in the intenet.

Comment: I think the summary screen is poorly worded. If you click through, the actual reason that person selected was *"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. ..."*.  Questions that do not include what code you tried, and the results, tend to prompt a lot of close votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

By default CF uses UTF-8 to decode URL variables. ["To decode .. URL variables in any other encoding ... you must use the setEncoding function."](http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/internationalization/internationalization_cfmx/internationalization_cfmx3.html)

```
<cfscript>
   setEncoding("URL", "shift_jis");
   writeDump(URL.brand); // result 日�Y自動車 
</cfscript>
```

---

When you have questions like this, the first place to look is in the [Functions by Category](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6a3a) view of the documentation. All of the functions are descriptively named. You can usually figure out the function you need by its name alone.  If you look over the [String Functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6a3a) section, you will find two functions that (combined) should do the trick:

- [`CharsetDecode(string, encoding)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f64.html) - Decodes a string in the given encoding into binary
- [`CharsetEncode(binary, encoding)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f63.html) - Converts binary into a string using the specified encoding

Comment: Leigh I Tried Hard, but no help.
`<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <cfscript> 
        chardecode=CharsetDecode(url.brand, "shift_jis"); 
        charencode=CharsetEncode(chardecode, "UTF-8"); 
    </cfscript> 
    <cfdump var="#chardecode#"></p> 
    <cfdump var="#charencode#"></p> 
    <cfabort> ` DISPLAY Following Output: `???Y?????? ` .
Run the page with /index.cfm?brand=%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4

Comment: That's the syntax of mb_convert_encoding (string $str , string $to_encoding , $from_encoding ] .

Comment: What is the format of your input "%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4"? I am not an encoding expert, but it does not look like UTF-8 from what I can tell. It decodes directly as JIS: `urldecode("%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4", "shift_jis")`

Comment: Leigh: "%93%FA%8EY%8E%A9%93%AE%8E%D4" is Shift-JIS string Format.

Comment: @ritesh_NITW - Sorry, my misunderstanding. You need a different function. See my update.

Comment: Hm.. It works w/Railo. Unfortunately I won't be near an ACF install to test it for about an hour. Hopefully someone else will chime in, in the mean time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37068/discussion-between-leigh-and-ritesh-nitw)